# How to use repmat to reshape a 1d vector into a 3d matrix?

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array

I can create a `10x10x3` matrix with the following:

```
A(1:10,1:10,1) = 1/4;
A(1:10,1:10,2) = 1/2;
A(1:10,1:10,3) = 1/4;
```

How can this be done using `repmat` and the vector `[1/4 1/2 1/4]'` given?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`repmat`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) to replicate your data, then [`permute`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) to set it in the correct dimensional order. The need for the `permute` arises from the use of column-major order by `repmat`, requiring you to first create the three correct `10x10` slices, then switch the first and third dimensions using `permute`.

```
A = [1/4 1/2 1/4].'; % your data
B = repmat(A,1,10,10); % use repmat to create a 3x10x10 copy
C=permute(B,[3 2 1]); % permute to the correct order

ans(:,:,1) =

    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500
    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500
    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500
    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500
    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500
    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500
    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500
    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500
    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500
    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500


ans(:,:,2) =

    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000
    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000
    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000
    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000
    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000
    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000
    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000
    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000
    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000
    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000


ans(:,:,3) =

    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500
    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500
    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500
    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500
    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500
    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500
    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500
    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500
    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500
    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500
```

Comment: It may be faster to first `permute` (or `reshape`) and then `repmat`, because that way the permuting/reshaping is done with less elements: `A = [1/4 1/2 1/4].'; B = repmat(reshape(A,1,1,[]),10,10);`

Comment: Or `A=cat( 3 , 1/3 , 1/2 , 1/4 );
B = repmat(A,10,10);` to further simplify the code.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't insist on using `repmat`, then you can use `ones` and `bsxfun`:

```
N = 10;
v = [1/4 1/2 1/4];
A = ones(N,N,3);
A = bsxfun(@times,A,permute(v,[3 1 2]))
```

This will create an `N x N x 3` array, each element of which is `1`. Then we multiply each submatrix (from `1` to `3` in the last index) with a corresponding value from `v`, this is achieved with `bsxfun`. For this we have to introduce leading singleton dimensions in `v` (turning it into `[1 x 1 x 3]`), this is what the call to `permute` is for.

**Update:** As [**@Divakar**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3293881/divakar) noted in a comment, you can omit the last dimension when first defining `A`:

```
N = 10;
v = [1/4 1/2 1/4];
A = ones(N,N); %one less dimension
A = bsxfun(@times,A,permute(v,[3 1 2]))
```

The reason for this is that in matlab, every variable is assumed to have an infinite number of *trailing* singleton dimensions (this is why `reshape(rand(2),[2 2 1 1 1])` returns a `[2 x 2]` array instead of a `[2 x 2 x 1 x 1 x 1]` one: the trailing singleton dimensions are implicitly present, and are therefore omitted). In this case you multiply an `[N x N]` matrix with an `[1 x 1 x 3]` one, but the former is implicitly interpreted as an `[N x N x 1]` one. `bsxfun` takes care of the rest.

Comment: You could even start off with a 2D `A` I think, `bsxfun` would take care of the last dim expansion.